# Can't deploy Azure VM with SSH configuration

Tags: azure

I try to deploy a VM machine with Azure but when I deploy I've this message below:

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidParameter",
        "target": "linuxConfiguration",
        "message": "Authentication via SSH or username and password must be enabled in the Linux profile."
    }
}
```

Template ARM:

https://pastebin.com/u4ZrhBvs

I added the ARM template above, but for this deployment I used the Azure portal entirely. I will use the template later

I don't really understand how can I fix that because the VM is not created and I don't have access to it?

Comment: Do you use Azure Portal to create new VM?

Comment: Please upload the ARM Template if you are using it to create a VM.

Comment: I added it on a pastebin, otherwise I can't post it @JagratiModi-AIS

Comment: @AndriyBilous I use Azure portal for the moment, but I scope to deploy with Azure ARM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ARM template you disabled password authentication but did not specified SSH key options

```
                "osProfile": {
                "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachineComputerName')]",
                "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                "linuxConfiguration": {
                    "disablePasswordAuthentication": true
                }
            },
```

Your `osProfile` with SSH key option should look like this

```
"osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[variables('vmName')]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "linuxConfiguration": {
            "disablePasswordAuthentication": true,
            "ssh": {
              "publicKeys": [
                {
                  "path": "[concat('/home/', parameters('adminUsername'), '/.ssh/authorized_keys')]",
                  "keyData": "[parameters('adminPublicKey')]"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
```

Here is an example how to create Linux VM from ARM template

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-ssh-secured-vm-from-template